# Which is most appropriate for this situation; Document Library or Item List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, document-library

The company I work for is currently going through a lot of changes, one of which is the decommissioning of a server that contains all attachments for [BCM Remedy](http://www.bmc.com/it-solutions/remedy-itsm.html) tickets. Before doing so though, I was tasked with migrating (and archiving) those attachments to SharePoint Online, and so I'm currently researching which method out there would be most ideal.

For each ticket (roughly 80k of them), there's just the ticket # and then a collection of attachments (multiple attachments for a single ticket is quite prevalent); they are comprised of all kinds of file types. As time goes by, these tickets will be accessed less and less, and are actually barely accessed even now, as is.

The two methods I'm considering for storage and retrieval of these attachments is either a [Document Library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-Document-Center-site-06096070-d83f-45b8-b02d-ec7a4cf85cac) or an [Item List](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-is-a-list-in-SharePoint-Online-93262a88-20ad-4edc-8410-b6909b2f59a5). My question is: which of these would be better for pure storage and retrieval? The only criteria that will be used to search for a ticket is the ticket #.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use both, Document Library as well as a custom list. Your documents will be stored in a document library and your custom list can be used to retrieve the location of documents(attachments) from the document library. Documents can be retrieved using a ticket number.

Comment: So, you're suggesting that I create a custom list view that will contain the ticket #, and a URL to the corresponding location within the document library? And so, users would initially only interface with the item list, and then be redirected to the documents (attachments) within the document library via URL?

Comment: Yes Charles, that is correct. User will interface with the item list and it will be faster response for users.

Comment: I believe I'll try this approach. Thanks for the advice!! I hope it works out :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple attachments associated with a single item then a document set in a document library might make sense as each document set can have custom properties, but can contain multiple documents.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple documents per ticket. If the ticket # is the only search criteria though, would the availability of those custom properties be excessive/overkill?

Comment: You can name the doc set after the ticket number instead of making it a property. Alternately, you can do a document library and add on a property to the individual documents. The biggest decider is whether you want to be able to easily navigate to/link to a collection of documents rather than going to the library and searching for the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated Azure storage?  SPO storage is high-availability and, as such, is expensive.  An Azure 'file share'-like setup might be a less expensive option for files which are not accessed frequently.

Comment: We *have* to use SPO..everything is going to SPO now, given the changes that are going on.

Comment: Too bad.  Then I agree with @Graham that document sets are your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieval would be more straight forward if they were contained as documents in a library rather than as attachments on list items. The search results would be much simpler, and would have access to built in info on filetypes, size etc. To retrieve attachments on list items there would be less you could provide to the user as they would only be returned as links.

I don't think the storage criteria would be any different.